# How can I export emojis in color from Inkskape?

Tags: inkscape, emoji

I'm trying to use emojis in Inkskape, but struggling to export them as their intended colorized objects. Inkscape shows them as black/white outlines, but the SVGs view correctly in a browser. Likely because the browser is showing the rendered font emoji.

Is there a way to get Inkscape to to properly export the emoji as rendered font?

Is there a better way to get emoji into Inkscape "natively"?

Comment: Hi. Inkscape doesn't currently support the display of colour emojis - only a black and white version, and there is no way to export a colour raster image of colour emojis either.  A workaround is to open the SVG in a browser (which should display the emojis in colour), and take a screen shot if you want a raster image.

Comment: Another option is to use GIMP if you want to create a raster image of some colour emojis. Just type them with the Text tool (making sure you select the correct font). Then from there you can export as PNG.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you call emoji.

There are basically two kinds.

One is a Unicode code, meaning that it will take the specific letter from a font, with the shape of the emoji. Some applications take the source font from different places. That is why you have different emoji styles. Some are application specific.

If you want vector files, you need to download them as files. This is the second kind.

Google something like this:
https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=svg+emoji

Or right-click and copy one you see online or in a browser to get a raster image.